# DateTime.Now - Metro App - Windows 8

Tags: datetime, timezone, winjs

I'm using DateTime.Now to display current time and date in my metro (windows 8) application (c# + winjs).

When the user change the TimeZone, without close and reopen the application,  the DateTime.Now show the old time.

(Works fine when the user close and reopen the app)

How to get the correct time?

Thanks

Comment: more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/731dfd25-e717-4a1c-bbf8-fc37cfc19fc0/a-bug-about-timezoneinfo-in-metro-app?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand - you're using C# and JavaScript (WinJS)? Do you mean that you're creating a WinJS app that calls into a C# runtime component?

Comment: I have a metro application written in WinJS and a C# WinRT Component (DLL)

Answer (score 1):

In a standard app, you could use `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData`, but this isn't available in a Windows Store application.

You could consider using [the WinRTTimeZones library](https://github.com/onovotny/WinRTTimeZones), which offers a different API, and [fetches the time zone from windows](https://github.com/onovotny/WinRTTimeZones/blob/4503229fc065ffaa69707e33109e4d9b3ca44183/TimeZones.NetCore/Internal/TimeZoneInfoEx.cs#L233-L247) using the `GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation` native Win32 call to get the time zone.

**Disclaimer:** I have no experience with this library.  It seems to have the right idea, but if you run into problems, please direct your questions at the author of the library.  Thanks.

Comment: We use this library to get the correct Daylight Time. We need to update the time using DateTime.Now or DateTime.UtcNow, but none of these values are updated when the user change the TimeZone :(

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx

Try out DateTime.UtcNow, basically

Comment: To clarify: then check what timezone they're in, and deal with the difference from there.

Comment: No, the problem is related to Cached TimeZone in metro apps